# How to parse received data into array in devise user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, post

How to undertake in model and parse to array user_location so that I can then parse to_lng_lat like in manual example?

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Geospatial

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable

  field :email,              :type => String, :default => ""
  field :encrypted_password, :type => String, :default => ""

  field :user_location,      :type => Point, :spatial => true

  before_save :set_user_location

  protected 
    def set_user_location 
      # manual save works
      # self.user_location = [52.38, 18.91].to_lng_lat
    end
end
```

Overridden devise user_controller:

```
def update
  puts JSON.parse params[:user][:user_location] 
  # gives raw:
  # 52.38 
  # 18.91
  super
end
```

Is it possible to do this without overriding devise controller only in model?

View:

```
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f|
    = f.email_field :email
    = f.password_field :current_password
    = f.hidden_field :user_location
    = f.submit "Update"
```

JavaScript:

```
var user_location = JSON.stringify([52.38, 18.91]);
$("#user_user_location").val(user_location);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than create a separate setter in the `User` model, you may be able to override the setter provided the `field :user_location` declaration. Since these setters are used implicitly via passing attributes to a model, I believe this would allow you to avoid making any specific changes to the controller to support JSON parsing for location.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # rest of class omitted, remove 'set_user_location' code

  def user_location=(location)
    case location
    when String
      super(JSON.parse(location))
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

This would be preferable to me rather than overriding the devise controller; I wouldn't have to think about doing this conversion in every context or controller where the data is set in this way.